# How to invoke Ant in Jenkins pipeline job using groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ant, jenkins-pipeline

I am changing my Freestyle Jenkins job configuration to Pipeline.  I need to Invoke Ant to perform LogPublisherTask and ArtifactFilePublisherTask. How is it performed using Groovy scripting?

Answer (score 5):

You invoke ant just like you do it with maven (take a look at examples https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/jenkinsfile/):

```
 node ('linux'){
  stage 'Build and Test'
  env.PATH = "${tool 'Ant'}/bin:${env.PATH}"
  checkout scm
  sh 'ant build'
 }
```

The tasks themselves should be configured in the `build.xml`.

Comment: If you need this on a window system, replace **sh** with **bat**

Comment: And remember to configure the ant tool in the jenkins "Global Tool Configuration" with the same name.

Comment: With regard to location of ant, this seems a little easier on the eyes: `withAnt(installation: 'ant-newest', jdk: 'jdk8') {
    // some block
}`