# How to invoke Ant in a Jenkins Groovy Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ant, jenkins-pipeline, sap-commerce-cloud

I have created a Jenkins Pipeline job. In this job I want to do the build using Ant. I have configured the Ant variable in Manage `**Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration**` as `Ant1.9.1= D:\path_to_hybris\hybris\bin\platform\apache-ant-1.9.1`.

In a freestyle jenkins Job, I know that the build.xml location can be specified as in the below screenshot: [image]

but I am unable to understand how to specify the ant groovy script beyond this point, especially where can we mention the path to build.xml file:

```
def antHome = tool 'Ant1.9.1'
????
????
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invoke Ant in Jenkins pipeline job using groovy script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103958/how-to-invoke-ant-in-jenkins-pipeline-job-using-groovy-script)

Answer (score 9):

you can use ant wrapper in Jenkins`s pipeline groovy script.

```
withAnt(installation: 'LocalAnt') {
// some block
   sh "ant build"
//for windows 
   bat "ant build"
}
```

Remember to configure the ant tool in the Jenkins "Global Tool Configuration" with the same name "LocalAnt".

Comment: for the `sh "ant build"` do I need to put the path to the build xml file or will simply typing `"ant build" work?

Comment: use something like `sh "ant -f build.xml all"` where `build.xml`is the path to the build file and `all` is the target.
the complete looks like this:
`withAnt(installation: 'Ant1.9.1')
{
  sh "ant -f build.xml all"
}` where `Ant1.9.1` is the name of the Ant installation in Jenkins

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

```
def antVersion = 'Ant1.9.1'
withEnv( ["ANT_HOME=${tool antVersion}"] ) {
    sh '$ANT_HOME/bin/ant target1 target2'
}
```

Under Windows this would look like this (I didn't test it though):

```
def antVersion = 'Ant1.9.1'
withEnv( ["ANT_HOME=${tool antVersion}"] ) {
    bat '%ANT_HOME%/bin/ant.bat target1 target2'
}
```

This assumes that you have Ant configured in Jenkins with name 'Ant1.9.1'.

Answer (score 2):

I needed this multiple times within the same Jenkinsfile that needs to be executed on both linux and windows agents so I created a method for it.

You can call ant like this

```
callAnt("-v -p")
```

if you add this method definition to your jenkinsfile

```
def callAnt(String Parameters) {
    if (isUnix()) {
        env.PATH = "${tool 'ant'}/bin;${env.PATH}"
        sh "ant ${Parameters}"
    }
    else {
        env.PATH = "${tool 'ant'}\\bin;${env.PATH}"
        bat "ant ${Parameters}"
    }
}
```