# Jenkins Unable to Detect the Ant

Tags: jenkins, ant

I have installed jenkins in windows machine, and i configured environment variable as well.
When i am checking ant -version in cmd i can able to get the response from the terminal "Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on June 27 2008".

**Jenkins Configuration**

Ant plugin installed.
Ant home configured in jenkins

[Ant config in jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVEmW.png)

I am checking ant -version in pipeline script, but i am getting build failed in jenkins with following error message "ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

```
stage('studio'){
          steps { 
                bat 'ant -version'
            }
      }
```

Can you please someone help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are mssing some details in the construction .. bat does not know about ant. See [How to invoke Ant in a Jenkins Groovy Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384971/how-to-invoke-ant-in-a-jenkins-groovy-pipeline)

```
def antVersion = 'Ant1.9.1'
withEnv( ["ANT_HOME=${tool antVersion}"] ) {
      bat '%ANT_HOME%/bin/ant.bat target1 target2'`
}
```

Also, don't name it ANT_HOME, but something relevant like `ant-1.7.1`